# Automatically load files from gcs bucket to bigquery in the order of object created time

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-composer

I want to load multiple CSV files from my google cloud storage bucket to Bigquery table. Consider that I have the same schema for all the CSV files and want to store all files in a single Bigquery table. The condition is 'I have to load them in the order of file created time'. If I mention the file names in the source_objects, it loads data in random order.
Here is my code.

```
with models.DAG(    
    dag_id="sample_id",
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval='@once'
) as dag:
    GCS_to_BQ= GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='gcs-bq',
        bucket='bucket_name',
        source_objects=['sample*.csv'], #wildcard
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        destination_project_dataset_table='dataset.dest_table_name',
        schema_fields=[{"name":"ID", "type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"Name","type":"String"},{"name":"Email","type":"STRING"},] ,
        source_format='CSV',
        #create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        dag=dag
        )
```

Comment: Why the order matter? It doesn't make sense

Comment: As per the documentation, source_objects doesn't allow wildcards. use full file name/s in the list